# Verwendung des umgangssprachlichen Verbs "bongen"

Tags: meaning, etymology, verb

Mir ist die Redewendung

> Ist gebongt!

geläufig. Sie ist eine umgangssprachliche Form von *"ist ausgemacht!*".

Anscheinend ist *gebongt* das Partizip Perfekt von *bongen*. Ist dieses Verb – außerhalb des oben erwähnten Ausdrucks in Verwendung? Ich habe es in meiner Umgebung noch nie gehört. Was ist die Hauptbedeutung von *bongen*? Ist es ein Neologismus oder gab es das Wort schon früher?

Comment: Oh wow, eine extrem coole Frage!

Comment: Beim Lesen der Frage dachte ich erst an die eigenmächtige Kreation eines Verbs für 'Bong rauchen'. :) Aber 'tüten' sagt man ja auch nicht.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Wenn man der [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kassenbon#Trivia) glauben darf, kommt diese Redewendung vom Aufnehmen einer Bestellung oder eines Artikels auf einen **Kassenbon**.

Wenn etwas auf dem Kassenbon ist, so ist es registiert, somit gebon(g)t. Im Gastgewerbe spricht man auch vom "einbongen", das Wort selbst wird aber so gut wie nie aufgeschrieben. Das "g" ist in der mündlichen Sprache an dieser Stelle wahrscheinlich entstanden, weil das Wort sonst nicht auszusprechen wäre, und hat sich dann entsprechend in der Schriftsprache manifestiert.

Der [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/bongen) sieht es ähnlich.

Comment: Das zusätzliche "g" ist ziemlich verbreitet als deutscher "Ersatz" für französische Nasale, oder? Besonders häufig höre ich es bei nicht mehr ganz jungen Sprechern aus dem Nordosten - hat auch jemand anderer ähnliche Beobachtungen gemacht? Ich versuche, gerade krampfhaft, Beispiele zu finden, aber mir fällt absolut keines ein... :(  Außerdem findet man es ziemlich oft in alten Filmen, wenn jemand übertrieben "preußisch" dargestellt werden soll - speziell etwas ältliche Militärs mit Monokel :)

Comment: Stimmt, beim Skat im "Salong" spielt man auch gerne mal einen "Grang" (falls gerade Winter-"Saisong") ist...

Comment: @Mac wie "Ballong"? :) Das ist übrigens das schwedische Wort für "Ballon".

Comment: @Jan + splatne: Danke - die Beispiele sind super! (Mir fällt immer als erstes eine Kommilitonin ein, die den Maler Campin wie "Kampäng" ausgesprochen hat...)

Comment: @splattne Die Schweden schreiben Fremdwörter oft wie man sie spricht, z.B. habe ich schon "tajming" in Dagens Nyheter gelesen. "Salong" ist übrigens auch schwedisch.

Comment: @Mac: Hier drin dürftest du mehr als genug Beispiele finden: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_von_Gallizismen